# Hiding options in one dropdown depending on selection in another

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have a web form & database system setup and is fit for purpose. The user selects a station from the first dropdown and then they have to select an error code from the next dropdown.

There is one complaint however, once the selection is chosen from the “Station” dropdown the error codes are still displayed for all of the other stations also.
It would be ideal if only the error codes corresponding to the selection from the “Station” dropdown were displayed.

I believe jQuery could help me out here but I’m more up to speed with PHP/ MySql rather than jQuery, can anyone help?

Dropdown for "Station"

```
<h3>Station</h3>
            <select name="STATION" id="STATION">
                <option value="" disabled selected>--Select a Station--    </option>
                <option value="AOI">AOI</option>
                <option value="AqueousCleaner">AqueousCleaner</option>
                <option value="Au_Au">Au_Au</option>
                <option value="CFA">CFA</option>
                <option value="Cleaner_1">Cleaner_1</option>
                <option value="Cleaner_2">Cleaner_2</option>
                <option value="Conveyor">Conveyor</option>
                <option value="Cure_Oven">Cure_Oven</option>
                <option value="Dage">Dage</option>
                <option value="DEK">DEK</option>
                <option value="EAS">EAS</option>
                <option value="EpoxyDotDispense">EpoxyDotDispense</option>
                <option value="GoldBallBonder">GoldBallBonder</option>
                <option value="GSI">GSI</option>
                <option value="GSMX">GSMX</option>
                <option value="LaserMark">LaserMark</option>
                <option value="LPKF">LPKF</option>
                <option value="MechanicalExcise">MechanicalExcise</option>
                <option value="Misc">Misc</option>
                <option value="MPS">MPS</option>
                <option value="Nikon">Nikon</option>
                <option value="Nordson">Nordson</option>
                <option value="PlasmaClean">PlasmaClean</option>
                <option value="PreBakeOven">PreBakeOven</option>
                <option value="Reflow">Reflow</option>
                <option value="RMI">RMI</option>
                <option value="Siemens">Siemens</option>
                <option value="SPI">SPI</option>
                <option value="Underfill_1">Underfill_1</option>
                <option value="Underfill_2">Underfill_2</option>
                <option value="Underfill_3">Underfill_3</option>
                <option value="Underfill_4">Underfill_4</option>
                <option value="UV_Cure">UV_Cure</option>
            </select>
```

Dropdown for "Error Code"

```
<h3>Error Code</h3>
            <td>
            <select name ="ERROR" id ="ERROR">
            <optgroup label="AOI">
                <option>Camera</option>
                <option>Conveyor</option>
                <option>Axis_Control</option>
                <option>PSU</option>
                <option>Software</option>
                <option>Watchdog</option>
                <option>Misc</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="AqueousCleaner">
                <option>Nozzles</option>
                <option>Detergent</option>
                <option>Pump</option>
                <option>PSU</option>
                <option>Software</option>
                <option>Watchdog</option>
                <option>Misc</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Au-Au">
                <option>Software_Crash</option>
                <option>Ultrasonic_Issue</option>
                <option>Fiducial_Error</option>
                <option>Axis_Fault</option>
                <option>Stage_Vacuum_Error</option>
                <option>Watchdog_Error</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="CFA">
                <option>Software</option>
                <option>Misc</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Cleaner 1 & 2">
                <option>Basket_Crash</option>
                <option>Solvent_level_Issue</option>
                <option>Transport_Issue</option>
                <option>Refrigeration_Fault</option>
                <option>Heater_Fault</option>
                <option>Watchdog_Error</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Conveyor">
                <option>Conveyor</option>
                <option>Axis_Control</option>
                <option>PSU</option>
                <option>Software</option>
                <option>Misc</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Cure Oven">
                <option>Watchdog_Error</option>
                <option>Conveyor_Alarm</option>
                <option>Heater_Alarm</option>
                <option>Blower_Fan</option>
                <option>Software_Crash</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Dage">
                <option>Hook</option>
                <option>Cartridge</option>
                <option>Software</option>
                <option>Pnuematic</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="DEK">
                <option>Conveyor</option>
                <option>Squeegee_Blade</option>
                <option>Fiducial_Read_Error</option>
                <option>Watchdog_Error</option>
                <option>Camera</option>
                <option>Axis_Control</option>
                <option>PSU</option>
                <option>Software</option>
                <option>Watchdog</option>
                <option>Misc</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="EAS">
                <option>Misc</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Epoxy Dot Dispense">
                <option>Broken_Needle</option>
                <option>Axis_Fault</option>
                <option>Defective_Pump</option>
                <option>Head_Crash</option>
                <option>Software_Crash</option>
                <option>Vision_Fault</option>
                <option>Watchdog_Error</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Gold Ball Bonder">
                <option>Software</option>
                <option>Fiducial</option>
                <option>Heaters</option>
                <option>Vacuum</option>
                <option>Wire_Spool</option>
                <option>Clamps</option>
                <option>Capillary</option>
                <option>Pnuematic_Alarm</option>
                <option>Magazine</option>
                <option>Conveyor</option>
                <option>Magazine_Lift</option>
                <option>Pallet_Transfer</option>
                <option>Misc</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="GSI">
                <option>Laser</option>
                <option>Conveyor</option>
                <option>Axis_Control</option>
                <option>PSU</option>
                <option>Software</option>
                <option>Watchdog</option>
                <option>Misc</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="GSMX">
                <option>Tooling</option>
                <option>Feeder_Error</option>
                <option>Nozzle</option>
                <option>Fiducials</option>
                <option>Misplaced_Tab</option>
                <option>Conveyor_Alarm</option>
                <option>Tab_Segregation</option>
                <option>Bent_Leads</option>
                <option>Software_Crash</option>
                <option>Watchdog_Error</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="LaserMark">
                <option>Laser</option>
                <option>Conveyor</option>
                <option>Axis_Control</option>
                <option>PSU</option>
                <option>Software</option>
                <option>Watchdog</option>
                <option>Misc</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="LPKF">
                <option>Laser_Fault</option>
                <option>Extraction_Issue</option>
                <option>Transfer_Issue</option>
                <option>Axis_Fault</option>
                <option>Fiducial_Error</option>
                <option>Not_Excised_Fully</option>
                <option>Vision_Fault</option>
                <option>Software_Crash</option>
                <option>Watchdog_Error</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Mechanical Excise">
                <option>Software_Crash</option>
                <option>Spindle_Pressure_Fault</option>
                <option>Fiducial_Error</option>
                <option>Axis_Fault</option>
                <option>Watchdog_Error</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Miscellaneous">
                <option>Misc</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="MPS">
                <option>Camera</option>
                <option>Software</option>
                <option>Watchdog</option>
                <option>Misc</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Nikon">
                <option>Axis_Control</option>
                <option>PSU</option>
                <option>Software</option>
                <option>Watchdog</option>
                <option>Misc</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Nordson">
                <option>Conveyor</option>
                <option>Sensor</option>
                <option>Vacuum</option>
                <option>Heater</option>
                <option>Blower</option>
                <option>Pnuematic</option>
                <option>Fiducial</option>
                <option>Lift</option>
                <option>Dispense_Nozzle</option>
                <option>Vacuum_Cup</option>
                <option>Weight_Fail</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Plasma Clean">
                <option>Board_Transfer</option>
                <option>Sensor_Alarm</option>
                <option>RF_Generator</option>
                <option>GAS_Flow</option>
                <option>Watchdog_Error</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="PreBakeOven">
                <li class="dropdown-header">PreBakeOven
                <option>Heaters</option>
                <option>Blowers</option>
                <option>Chiller</option>
                <option>Conveyor</option>
                <option>PSU</option>
                <option>Software</option>
                <option>Watchdog</option>
                <option>Misc</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Reflow">
                <li class="dropdown-header">Reflow
                <option>Heaters</option>
                <option>Blowers</option>
                <option>Chiller</option>
                <option>Conveyor</option>
                <option>PSU</option>
                <option>Software</option>
                <option>Watchdog</option>
                <option>Misc</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="RMI">
                <option>Software</option>
                <option>Misc</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Siemens">
                <option>Feeder</option>
                <option>Nozzle</option>
                <option>Fiducial</option>
                <option>Axis_Control</option>
                <option>Twin_Head</option>
                <option>Star_Head</option>
                <option>Software_Crash</option>
                <option>Watchdog_Error</option>
                <option>Camera</option>
                <option>Conveyor</option>
                <option>MTC</option>
                <option>Good_Bad_Marks</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="SPI">
                <option>Camera</option>
                <option>Conveyor</option>
                <option>Axis_Control</option>
                <option>PSU</option>
                <option>Software</option>
                <option>Watchdog</option>
                <option>Misc</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Underfill 1 - 4">
                <option>Blocked_Nozzle</option>
                <option>Damaged_Nozzle</option>
                <option>Axis_Fault</option>
                <option>Defective_Pump</option>
                <option>Heater_Plates</option>
                <option>Broken_Piston</option>
                <option>Head_Crash</option>
                <option>Software_Crash</option>
                <option>Broken_Needle</option>
                <option>Vision_Fault</option>
                <option>Watchdog_Error</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="UV_Cure">
                <option>Conveyor</option>
                <option>Sensor</option>
                <option>Bulb</option>
                <option>Controls</option>
                <option>Inter_Lock</option>
                <option>Door</option>
                <option>Misc</option>
            </optgroup>
            </select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easiest to Clone the "Errors" select then pull the html from the optgroup on station select change. You may have to tweek the html of your Errors so that the optgroup label matches the value from your station. (creating 2 optgroups out of "cleaner 1 & 2") But the opt groups will never show anyway except before a station is selected.  http://jsfiddle.net/vd9zvbLd/

```
$(function(){
    var $errors = $('#ERROR').clone();
    $('#STATION').change(function(){
        var station = $(this).val();
        var errs = $errors.find('optgroup[label="' + station + '"]').html();
        $('#ERROR').html(errs);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that Gregg!

Answer (score 3):

```
// This fires any time the STATION select box is changed
$("#STATION").on("change", function() {

    // Find the chosen station (or blank if nothing selected)
    var station = $(this).find(":selected").val();

    // Hide and show the optgroups in the second dropdown accordingly
    if(station != "")
    {
        // Hides all optgroups, then shows only the selected one
        $("#ERROR").children("optgroup").hide(); // Hide all
        $("#ERROR").children("optgroup[label='" + station + "']").show();
    }
    else 
    {
        // If they change back to the 'Choose a station' option, show everything
        $("#ERROR").children("optgroup").show();
    }

});
```

That should do the trick, you would have to make sure that the value attributes in the first dropdown matched up with the label attributes in the second dropdown however.

Answer (score 3):

try this one, hidding all the errors firstly then show the error codes related to the Station, everytime the user change station hide all and show just associated error codes.

```js
$(function(){
  
    //Hide all error codes
    $('#ERROR optgroup').addClass('hidden');
  
    //Handel Station change event
    $('#STATION').on('change',function()
    {
        //Hide all error codes
        $('#ERROR optgroup').addClass('hidden');
      
        //Show the associate Error codes related with the shoosen station
        $('#ERROR optgroup[label="'+$(this).val()+'"]').removeClass("hidden");
    });
});
```

```css
.hidden{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Station</h3>
            <select name="STATION" id="STATION">
                <option value="" disabled selected>--Select a Station--    </option>
                <option value="AOI">AOI</option>
                <option value="AqueousCleaner">AqueousCleaner</option>
                <option value="Au_Au">Au_Au</option>
                <option value="CFA">CFA</option>
                <option value="Cleaner_1">Cleaner_1</option>
                <option value="Cleaner_2">Cleaner_2</option>
                <option value="Conveyor">Conveyor</option>
                <option value="Cure_Oven">Cure_Oven</option>
                <option value="Dage">Dage</option>
                <option value="DEK">DEK</option>
                <option value="EAS">EAS</option>
                <option value="EpoxyDotDispense">EpoxyDotDispense</option>
                <option value="GoldBallBonder">GoldBallBonder</option>
                <option value="GSI">GSI</option>
                <option value="GSMX">GSMX</option>
                <option value="LaserMark">LaserMark</option>
                <option value="LPKF">LPKF</option>
                <option value="MechanicalExcise">MechanicalExcise</option>
                <option value="Misc">Misc</option>
                <option value="MPS">MPS</option>
                <option value="Nikon">Nikon</option>
                <option value="Nordson">Nordson</option>
                <option value="PlasmaClean">PlasmaClean</option>
                <option value="PreBakeOven">PreBakeOven</option>
                <option value="Reflow">Reflow</option>
                <option value="RMI">RMI</option>
                <option value="Siemens">Siemens</option>
                <option value="SPI">SPI</option>
                <option value="Underfill_1">Underfill_1</option>
                <option value="Underfill_2">Underfill_2</option>
                <option value="Underfill_3">Underfill_3</option>
                <option value="Underfill_4">Underfill_4</option>
                <option value="UV_Cure">UV_Cure</option>
            </select>

<h3>Error Code</h3>
<td>
    <select name ="ERROR" id ="ERROR">
        <option value="" disabled selected>--Select a Error Code--    </option>
        <optgroup label="AOI">
            <option>Camera</option>
            <option>Conveyor</option>
            <option>Axis_Control</option>
            <option>PSU</option>
            <option>Software</option>
            <option>Watchdog</option>
            <option>Misc</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="AqueousCleaner">
            <option>Nozzles</option>
            <option>Detergent</option>
            <option>Pump</option>
            <option>PSU</option>
            <option>Software</option>
            <option>Watchdog</option>
            <option>Misc</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Au-Au">
            <option>Software_Crash</option>
            <option>Ultrasonic_Issue</option>
            <option>Fiducial_Error</option>
            <option>Axis_Fault</option>
            <option>Stage_Vacuum_Error</option>
            <option>Watchdog_Error</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="CFA">
            <option>Software</option>
            <option>Misc</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Cleaner 1 & 2">
            <option>Basket_Crash</option>
            <option>Solvent_level_Issue</option>
            <option>Transport_Issue</option>
            <option>Refrigeration_Fault</option>
            <option>Heater_Fault</option>
            <option>Watchdog_Error</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Conveyor">
            <option>Conveyor</option>
            <option>Axis_Control</option>
            <option>PSU</option>
            <option>Software</option>
            <option>Misc</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Cure Oven">
            <option>Watchdog_Error</option>
            <option>Conveyor_Alarm</option>
            <option>Heater_Alarm</option>
            <option>Blower_Fan</option>
            <option>Software_Crash</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Dage">
            <option>Hook</option>
            <option>Cartridge</option>
            <option>Software</option>
            <option>Pnuematic</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="DEK">
            <option>Conveyor</option>
            <option>Squeegee_Blade</option>
            <option>Fiducial_Read_Error</option>
            <option>Watchdog_Error</option>
            <option>Camera</option>
            <option>Axis_Control</option>
            <option>PSU</option>
            <option>Software</option>
            <option>Watchdog</option>
            <option>Misc</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="EAS">
            <option>Misc</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Epoxy Dot Dispense">
            <option>Broken_Needle</option>
            <option>Axis_Fault</option>
            <option>Defective_Pump</option>
            <option>Head_Crash</option>
            <option>Software_Crash</option>
            <option>Vision_Fault</option>
            <option>Watchdog_Error</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Gold Ball Bonder">
            <option>Software</option>
            <option>Fiducial</option>
            <option>Heaters</option>
            <option>Vacuum</option>
            <option>Wire_Spool</option>
            <option>Clamps</option>
            <option>Capillary</option>
            <option>Pnuematic_Alarm</option>
            <option>Magazine</option>
            <option>Conveyor</option>
            <option>Magazine_Lift</option>
            <option>Pallet_Transfer</option>
            <option>Misc</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="GSI">
            <option>Laser</option>
            <option>Conveyor</option>
            <option>Axis_Control</option>
            <option>PSU</option>
            <option>Software</option>
            <option>Watchdog</option>
            <option>Misc</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="GSMX">
            <option>Tooling</option>
            <option>Feeder_Error</option>
            <option>Nozzle</option>
            <option>Fiducials</option>
            <option>Misplaced_Tab</option>
            <option>Conveyor_Alarm</option>
            <option>Tab_Segregation</option>
            <option>Bent_Leads</option>
            <option>Software_Crash</option>
            <option>Watchdog_Error</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="LaserMark">
            <option>Laser</option>
            <option>Conveyor</option>
            <option>Axis_Control</option>
            <option>PSU</option>
            <option>Software</option>
            <option>Watchdog</option>
            <option>Misc</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="LPKF">
            <option>Laser_Fault</option>
            <option>Extraction_Issue</option>
            <option>Transfer_Issue</option>
            <option>Axis_Fault</option>
            <option>Fiducial_Error</option>
            <option>Not_Excised_Fully</option>
            <option>Vision_Fault</option>
            <option>Software_Crash</option>
            <option>Watchdog_Error</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Mechanical Excise">
            <option>Software_Crash</option>
            <option>Spindle_Pressure_Fault</option>
            <option>Fiducial_Error</option>
            <option>Axis_Fault</option>
            <option>Watchdog_Error</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Miscellaneous">
            <option>Misc</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="MPS">
            <option>Camera</option>
            <option>Software</option>
            <option>Watchdog</option>
            <option>Misc</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Nikon">
            <option>Axis_Control</option>
            <option>PSU</option>
            <option>Software</option>
            <option>Watchdog</option>
            <option>Misc</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Nordson">
            <option>Conveyor</option>
            <option>Sensor</option>
            <option>Vacuum</option>
            <option>Heater</option>
            <option>Blower</option>
            <option>Pnuematic</option>
            <option>Fiducial</option>
            <option>Lift</option>
            <option>Dispense_Nozzle</option>
            <option>Vacuum_Cup</option>
            <option>Weight_Fail</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Plasma Clean">
            <option>Board_Transfer</option>
            <option>Sensor_Alarm</option>
            <option>RF_Generator</option>
            <option>GAS_Flow</option>
            <option>Watchdog_Error</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="PreBakeOven">
            <li class="dropdown-header">PreBakeOven
                <option>Heaters</option>
                <option>Blowers</option>
                <option>Chiller</option>
                <option>Conveyor</option>
                <option>PSU</option>
                <option>Software</option>
                <option>Watchdog</option>
                <option>Misc</option>
                </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Reflow">
                <li class="dropdown-header">Reflow
                    <option>Heaters</option>
                    <option>Blowers</option>
                    <option>Chiller</option>
                    <option>Conveyor</option>
                    <option>PSU</option>
                    <option>Software</option>
                    <option>Watchdog</option>
                    <option>Misc</option>
                    </optgroup>
                <optgroup label="RMI">
                    <option>Software</option>
                    <option>Misc</option>
                </optgroup>
                <optgroup label="Siemens">
                    <option>Feeder</option>
                    <option>Nozzle</option>
                    <option>Fiducial</option>
                    <option>Axis_Control</option>
                    <option>Twin_Head</option>
                    <option>Star_Head</option>
                    <option>Software_Crash</option>
                    <option>Watchdog_Error</option>
                    <option>Camera</option>
                    <option>Conveyor</option>
                    <option>MTC</option>
                    <option>Good_Bad_Marks</option>
                </optgroup>
                <optgroup label="SPI">
                    <option>Camera</option>
                    <option>Conveyor</option>
                    <option>Axis_Control</option>
                    <option>PSU</option>
                    <option>Software</option>
                    <option>Watchdog</option>
                    <option>Misc</option>
                </optgroup>
                <optgroup label="Underfill 1 - 4">
                    <option>Blocked_Nozzle</option>
                    <option>Damaged_Nozzle</option>
                    <option>Axis_Fault</option>
                    <option>Defective_Pump</option>
                    <option>Heater_Plates</option>
                    <option>Broken_Piston</option>
                    <option>Head_Crash</option>
                    <option>Software_Crash</option>
                    <option>Broken_Needle</option>
                    <option>Vision_Fault</option>
                    <option>Watchdog_Error</option>
                </optgroup>
                <optgroup label="UV_Cure">
                    <option>Conveyor</option>
                    <option>Sensor</option>
                    <option>Bulb</option>
                    <option>Controls</option>
                    <option>Inter_Lock</option>
                    <option>Door</option>
                    <option>Misc</option>
                </optgroup>
                </select>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Zakaria!

Comment: Hi Zakaria, thank you again for your help. I’ve noticed that the error codes are not displayed for stations with an underscore or for the station wrote in camel case. Do you know why this might be?
“Stations not displaying error codes”
Au_Au, Cleaner_1, Cleaner_2, Cure_Oven, EpoxyDotDispense, GoldBallBonder, MechanicalExcise, Misc, PlasmaClean, Underfill_1, Underfill_2, Underfill_3, Underfill_4

Comment: Yes i see, because we use the label of errors code optgroup, but unfortunately in some cases the value of statement not equal this label. e.g : `<optgroup label="Cleaner 1 & 2">` and the value of station = `Cleaner_1` or `Cleaner_1`.

Comment: ah perfect, thanks for the direction I will update my code. Kind regards.

Comment: Damn it! it works fine in Chrome & Fire fox but not IE11.. the browser everyone is using here.